# Subvarieties and finding ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hi guys I am stuck working on this problem. I have a surface $W= V(xz-y^2)$ and we are trying to find an ideal $J \in K[W]$ so that the $V_w(J)=V(y-x^2,z-x^3)$ I showed that the second thing which is the twisted cubic is indeed a subvariety, but I have no idea how to find such a J. How do you generaly look for such objects?

Thank,

Comment: Do you know all the ideals of $K[W]$ ? It might be helpful.

Comment: I mean what we know about $K[W]$ is that is the coordinate ring which is isomorphic to $K[x,y,z] /<xz-y^2>$

Comment: More generally, do you know the structure of the ideals of a ring of the form $A/I$, where $A$ is a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal ?

Comment: Yes we are assuming the ring is commutative, but we do not know anything else

Comment: Do you know that the ideals of $A/I$ are in bijection with the ideals of $A$ containing $I$? It helps a lot for your first question.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense,so J must contain the ideal $<xz-y^2>$

Comment: And you know that $J$ must contains the equations $y-x^2$ and $z-x^3$. Do you see an obvious $J$?

Comment: Im sorry I am blind..

Comment: Thank you I was just really out of it last night I see it now!!! Ha ha thank you